# error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 13 with netbean 11.3, jdk 13.0.1

Tags: java, tomcat, web, servlets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyEPL.png)
Hi guy! I am an absolute newbie with java web, I've tried to use servlet to create my first web app, I already installed tomcat and all environment is neccessary for java web application, but I got an error <<>> when I built project! Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: you should paste your code here instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi -- check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and as @HakanDilek says post us some code to help us help you.

Comment: Try Java 11 - that is the most recent long term support (LTS) version of Java.  Java 13 is already obsolete and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve it by modifying below attributes in nbproject\project.properties file as below. This also means that you are falling back to JDK8 instead of JDK13.

```
javac.compilerargs=
javac.source=1.8
javac.target=1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the

```
-Xbootclasspath/p
```

to

```
-J-Xbootclasspath/a
```

Comment: Where did you do this, please?